# Asynchronous & multi threading in php

Tags: php, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Threads in PHP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585656/threads-in-php)

I m getting a list of 20 urls.
I need to process some operation on these request simultaneously.

and my php execution will continue only after all request is over.

example

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<120;$i++)
{
  //parallel processing of 20 urls
}

come here only if all request are fullfilled
```

Comment: Why does it need to be simultaneous? What's wrong with doing it sequentially? Are you doing some kind of HTTP request that takes time to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inherent multi threading in php.

Instead what you could do is invoke 20 php-cli calls which don't return anything to the caller.  :)
(Thats bullish, but if there is lot of things to process, then it might be worth. Depends on your situation though)

You could also see [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

Someone else might come up with a better answer as well...

Edit:

Oh, and btw, if you were going to call those URLs, use @symcbean's answer, about [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) I didn't think in that angle at all :p

Answer (score 2):

See the [curl_multi_ functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to perform multiple simultaneous requests using the cURL library. Have a look at the `curl_multi_` functions.