# Make a separate "thread" in php

Tags: php, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Threads in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585656/threads-in-php)

Is it possible to make seperate thread to execute something time intensive in PHP? Theres a function that needs to contact an external server but the reply from that server is not important so it would be better to put it in a new thread instead of slowing the whole page load down a few seconds.

Comment: Please use the search before posting new questions. Many questions have already been asked and answered here on Stack Overflow!

Comment: http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no multi-threading in PHP. You can, however use the PCNTL functions to fork a child process.

Answer (score 1):

This is not php threads per se, however, based on your description, if you're running under *nix, you can handle this quite easily by putting the code you want to run asynchronously in a seperate script and calling it with the exec function using '&' to background the process.

```
exec('bgscript.php &');
```

Comment: Redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null by adding > /dev/null 2>/dev/null