# Is there threading in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one use multi threading in php applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)
>   [Does PHP have threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading)
>   [Threads in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585656/threads-in-php)

Is it possible to start separated threads that you can run multiple processes at a given time like you can in c# and java and etc in PHP?

If yes, how can it be done?

If no, why not? Perhaps this not a good idea for web environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not supports threads as such but you can create child processes which will act independently in a similar way to threads. See the PHP manual for details: https://www.php.net/pcntl_fork

Someone has also written [their own thread class](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/) which you can use.  It uses the `pcntl_fork` method and wraps it up a bit to make it similar to the java.lang.Thread implementation.