# I want to execute child php script without hampering current flow of parent script (return value is not important)

Tags: php

We have one function to send push notification in our application , and we want to execute this function as a child process without hampering parent process. The return value of this child function is not important . We can not use "PCNTL" functions as well as exec or any type of such functions to fork the process (we have stringiest requirement) . I have explored and researched for almost 2 months now, but did not get satisfactory solution . Any help will be much appreciated. (parent process should not wait for child process to complite and child process should start execution instantly.)

Comment: you should consider some "messaging queue" application like rabbitmq

Comment: thanks for suggestion , but we are looking for some short sweet php code which will not become headache afterwords ....  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As there aren't any threads in PHP ([Threads in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585656/threads-in-php)), any solution with have to either be fork/exec or some abstraction of them.

Comment: yes, i want something which works like those functions, some asynchronous ajax trick... may do the charm .... please suggest ...

Comment: Why not just use fork?

Comment: I would with pleasure if that was feasible , but the current situation demands solution other than those functions :-)

Comment: What are the extra requirements? The question, as is, is asking how to build a car without using wheels and doesn't giving motivation as to why wheels won't work.

Comment: There are not any extra requirements , My Question Is very simple and generic, We are using Old version of php in our project and pcntl library is in updated version also we can not update the version as we are using many truncated functions in it.Hence i need the solution which does not involve any built in extension .......