# Identify which PHP script is running?

Tags: php

I have a large PHP application and I'm looking for a way to know which PHP script is running at a given moment. Something like when you run "top" on a Linux command line but for PHP.

Comment: Have you looked at the `$_SERVER` superglobal array? It has some information on which file is currently executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to do so from within the PHP application, or outside of it? If you're inside the PHP code, entering `debug_print_backtrace();` at that point will show you the 'tree' of PHP files that were included to get you at that point.

If you're outside the PHP script, you can only see the one process that called the original PHP script (index.php or whatnot), unless the application spawns parallel threads as part of its execution.

Comment: @Byron: Yes it does: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php (needs to be compiled with PCNTL, but it's a possibility)

Comment: nah that is forking the process, similar but not the same as threading. You can read some user feedback on this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/209774/398519

Comment: Okay, so I just used the wrong term; PHP can "split off another process", which the point is would show up in `top` or similar as a separate process, which was what the OP may have been wanting, though I'm guessing it's the first half of my answer they need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for this information at the system level, e.g. all php files running under any Apache child process, or even any PHP files in use by other apps, there is the `lsof` program (list open files), which will spit out by default ALL open files on the system (executables, sockets, fifos, .so's, etc...). You can grep the output for '.php' and get a pretty complete picture of what's in use at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

This old post shows a way you can wrap your calls to php scripts and get a PID for each process.

[Does PHP have threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading)

```
$cmd = 'nohup nice -n 10 /usr/bin/php -c /path/to/php.ini -f /path/to/php/file.php action=generate  var1_id=23 var2_id=35 gen_id=535 > /path/to/log/file.log & echo $!';
$pid = shell_exec($cmd);
```