# Parallel processing in PHP - How do you do it?

Tags: php, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-queue

I am currently trying to implement a job queue in php. The queue will then be processed as a batch job and should be able to process some jobs in parallel.

I already did some research and found several ways to implement it, but I am not really aware of their advantages and disadvantages.

E.g. doing the parallel processing by calling a script several times through `fsockopen` like explained here:
[Easy parallel processing in PHP](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254)

Another way I found was using the `curl_multi` functions.
[curl_multi_exec PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)

But I think those 2 ways will add pretty much overhead for creating batch processing on a queue that should mainly run on the background?

I also read about `pcntl_fork` which also seems to be a way to handle the problem. But that looks like it can get really messy if you don't really know what you are doing (like me at the moment).

I also had a look at `Gearman`, but there I would also need to spawn the worker threads dynamically as needed and not just run a few and let the gearman job server then sent it to the free workers. Especially because the threads should be exit cleanly after one job has been executed, to not run into eventual memory leaks (code may not be perfect in that issue).
[Gearman Getting Started](http://gearman.org/index.php?id=getting_started)

So my question is, how do you handle parallel processing in PHP? And why do you choose your method, which advantages/disadvantages may the different methods have?

Comment: Accepted Quamis answer because thats how I'm going to do it now. Other answers where also good and may also have a look into their approaches in the futue. Thanks again.

Comment: For a detailed discussion about different aproaches see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading/14201579#14201579

Answer (score 24, accepted):

i use `exec()`. Its easy and clean. You basically need to build a thread manager, and thread scripts, that will do what you need.

I dont like `fsockopen()` because it will open a server connection, that will build up and may hit the apache's connection limit

I dont like `curl` functions for the same reason

I dont like `pnctl` because it needs the pnctl extension available, and you have to keep track of parent/child relations.

never played with gearman...

Comment: But how would your thread manager look like? The main problem I have is what would be a good way to create those threads and also let them exit cleanly after they finished their jobs.      
And `exec` blocks till the command is finished, so I cannot run the jobs in parallel or am I wrong here?

Comment: you can run things in background:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process

Comment: Ahh sure... Thanks, didn't really think about that :) Actually there is even already an [example code](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#88704) in the comments of the exec php manual, which also easily shows how to keep track of the processes then.

Comment: got to remember tho, that some servers do not allow exec() for seciurity reasons

Comment: @Gacek: that's actually PHP's config specific, not server-specific. If you dont have acces to the server config, it would be hard to do paralel processing anyway

Answer (score 15):

Well I guess we have 3 options there:

**A. Multi-Thread:**

PHP does not support multithread natively.
But there is one PHP extension (experimental) called pthreads (https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) that allows you to do just that.

**B. Multi-Process:**

This can be done in 3 ways:

- Forking
- Executing Commands
- Piping

**C. Distributed Parallel Processing:**

*How it works:*

1. The `Client` App sends data (AKA message) “can be JSON formatted” to the Engine (MQ Engine) “can be local or external a web service”
2. The `MQ Engine` stores the data “mostly in Memory and optionally in Database” inside a queues (you can define the queue name)
3. The `Client` App asks the MQ Engine for a data (message) to be processed them in order (FIFO or based on priority) “you can also request data from specific queue".

Some MQ Engines:

- **ZeroMQ** (good option, hard to use)
  a message orientated IPC Library, is a Message Queue Server in Erlang, stores jobs in memory. It is a socket library that acts as a concurrency framework. Faster than TCP for clustered products and supercomputing.
- **RabbitMQ** (good option, easy to use) 
  self hosted, Enterprise Message Queues, Not really a work queue - but rather a message queue that can be used as a work queue but requires additional semantics.
- **Beanstalkd** (best option, easy to use)
  (Laravel built in support, built by facebook, for work queue) - has a "Beanstalkd console" tool which is very nice
- **Gearman**
  (problem: centralized broker system for distributed processing)
- **Apache ActiveMQ**
  the most popular open source message broker in Java, (problem: lot of bugs and problems)
- **Amazon SQS**
  (Laravel built in support, Hosted - so no administration is required. Not really a work queue thus will require extra work to handle semantics such as burying a job)
- **IronMQ**
  (Laravel built in support, Written in Go, Available both as cloud version and on-premise)
- **Redis**
  (Laravel built in support, not that fast as its not designed for that)
- **Sparrow**
  (written in Ruby that based on memcache)
- **Starling** 
  (written in Ruby that based on memcache, built in twitter)
- **Kestrel**
  (just another QM)
- **Kafka**
  (Written at LinkedIn in Scala)
- **EagleMQ**
  open source, high-performance and lightweight queue manager (Written in C)

More of them can be foun here: http://queues.io

Comment: pthreads project halted and not compiling on php 7.4.x https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/929

Comment: php 8 now support multithread.https://www.php.net/parallel

Comment: not just php 8, but php 7.2+ also supports `parallel`

Answer (score 5):

Use native PHP (7.2+) [Parallel](https://www.php.net/manual/en/parallel.run.php) , i.e.:

```
use \parallel\Runtime;

$sampleFunc = function($num, $param2, $param3) { 
    echo "[Start: $num]";  
    sleep(rand(1,3) ); 
    echo "[end:$num]";   
};

for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) { 
    \parallel\run($sampleFunc,  [$param1=$i, $param2=null, $param3="blabla"] );
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
    echo " <REGULAR_CODE> ";
    sleep(1);
}
```

(BTW, you will need to go through hard path to install PHP with ZTS support, and then enable parallel. I recommend phpbrew to do that.)

Answer (score 4):

If your application is going to run under a unix/linux enviroment I would suggest you go with the forking option. It's basically childs play to get it working. I have used it for a Cron manager and had code for it to revert to a Windows friendly codepath if forking was not an option.

The options of running the entire script several times do, as you state, add quite a bit of overhead. If your script is small it might not be a problem. But you will probably get used to doing parallel processing in PHP by the way you choose to go. And next time when you have a job that uses 200mb of data it might very well be a problem. So you'd be better of learning a way that you can stick with.

I have also tested Gearman and I like it a lot. There are a few thing to think about but as a whole it offers a very good way to distribute works to different servers running different applications written in different languages. Besides setting it up, actually using it from within PHP, or any other language for that matter, is... once again... childs play.

It could very well be overkill for what you need to do. But it will open your eyes to new possibilities when it comes to handling data and jobs, so I would recommend you to try Gearman for that fact alone.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a summary of a few options for parallel processing in PHP.

### AMP

Checkout [*Amp - Asynchronous concurrency made simple*](https://amphp.org/) - this looks to be the most mature PHP library I've seen for parallel processing.

### Peec's Process Class

This class was posted in [the comments of PHP's exec() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#88704) and provides a real simple starting point for forking new processes and keeping track of them.

Example:

```
// You may use status(), start(), and stop(). notice that start() method gets called automatically one time.
$process = new Process('ls -al');

// or if you got the pid, however here only the status() metod will work.
$process = new Process();
$process.setPid(my_pid);

// Then you can start/stop/check status of the job.
$process.stop();
$process.start();
if ($process.status()) {
    echo "The process is currently running";
} else {
    echo "The process is not running.";
}
```

### Other Options Compared

There's also a great article [*Async processing or multitasking in PHP*](https://www.mullie.eu/parallel-processing-multi-tasking-php/) that explains the pros and cons of various approaches:

- [pthreads extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) (see also [this SitePoint article](https://www.sitepoint.com/parallel-programming-pthreads-php-fundamentals/))
- [Amp\Thread Library](https://github.com/amphp/thread)
- hack's async (requires running Facebook's HHVM)
- [pcntl_fork](https://php.net/pcntl_fork)
- [popen](https://php.net/popen)
- fopen/curl/fsockopen

### Doorman

Then, there's also [this simple tutorial](https://medium.com/async-php/multi-process-php-94a4e5a4be05) which was wrapped up into a little library called [*Doorman*](https://github.com/asyncphp/doorman).

Hope these links provide a useful starting point for more research.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this answer is based on the linux OS env.
Yet another pecl extension is parallel,you can install it by issuing `pecl install parallel`，but it has some prerequisities：

1. Installing ZTS(Zend Thread safety) Build PHP 7.2+ version
2. if you build this extension by source, you should check the php.ini like config file,then add `extension=parallel.so` to it

then see the full example gist :https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/0ee02b887288720d9b785c9f947f3a0a
or the php official site url:https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php

Comment: An easy howto : https://harry.plus/blog/install-php-7-4-zts-with-ext-parallel-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

I prefer exec() and gearman.
exec() is easy and no connection and less memory consuming.
gearman should need a socket connection and the worker should take some memory.
But gearman is more flexible and faster than exec(). And the most important is that it can deploy the worker in other server. If the work is time and resource consuming.
I'm using gearman in my current project.

Answer (score 2):

I use PHP's pnctl - it is good as long as you know what you do. I understand you situation but I don't think it's something difficult to understand our code, we just have to be little more conscious than ever when implementing JOB queue or Parallel process.

I feel as long as you code it perfectly and make sure the flow is perfect off-course you should keep PARALLEL PROCESS in mind when you implement.

Where you could do mistakes:

1. Loops - should be able to handle by GLOBAL vars.
2. Processing some set of transactions - again as long as you define the sets proper, you should be able to get it done.

Take a look at this example - https://github.com/rakesh-sankar/Tools/blob/master/PHP/fork-parallel-process.php.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The method described in 'Easy parallel processing in PHP' is downright scary - the principle is OK - but the implementation??? As you've already pointed out the curl_multi_ fns provide a much better way of implementing this approach.

> But I think those 2 ways will add pretty much overhead

Yes, you probably don't need a client and server HTTP stack for handing off the job - but unless you're working for Google, your development time is much more expensive than your hardware costs - and there are plenty of tools for managing HTTP/analysing performance - and there is a defined standard covering stuff such as status notifications and authentication.

A lot of how you implement the solution depends on the level transactional integrity you require and whether you require in-order processing.

Out of the approaches you mention I'd recommend focussing on the HTTP request method using curl_multi_ . But if you need good transactional control / in order delivery then you should definitely run a broker daemon between the source of the messages and the processing agents (there is a well written single threaded server suitable for use as a framework for the broker [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5758-PHP-Handle-requests-to-network-servers.html)). Note that the processing agents should process a single message at a time.

If you need a highly scalable solution, then take a look at a proper message queuing system such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

HTH

C.