# Running file_put_contents in parallel?

Tags: php, arrays, curl, foreach

was searching stackoverflow for a solution, but couldn't find anything even close to what I am trying to achieve. Perhaps I am just blissfully unaware of some magic PHP sauce everyone is doing tackling this problem... ;)

Basically I have an array with give or take a few hundred urls, pointing to different XML files on a remote server. I'm doing some magic file-checking to see if the content of the XML files have changed and if it did, I'll download newer XMLs to my server.

PHP code:

```
$urls = array(
    'http://stackoverflow.com/a-really-nice-file.xml',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/another-cool-file2.xml'
);
foreach($urls as $url){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
}
```

Now, $filename is set somewhere else and gives each xml it's own ID based on my logic.
So far this script is running OK and does what it should, but it does it terribly slow. I know my server can handle a lot more and I suspect my foreach is slowing down the process.

Is there any way I can speed up the foreach? Currently I am thinking to up the file_put_contents in each foreach loop to 10 or 20, basically cutting my execution time 10- or 20-fold, but can't think of how to approach this the best and most performance kind of way. Any help or pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: i do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107339/parallel-processing-in-php-how-do-you-do-it one script per cpu core seems to work best for me.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Hmm, actually there are just a handful of different servers. The performance I get is actually pretty good in terms of download speed of the xml's (which are only a few kb each). Basically I download the xml's, store the newest ones on my server, read them out and add their contents to my DB for fast indexing and search-ability on my frontend application.

Comment: @Dagon: Interesting. I'll take a closed look at it, but that solution would mean a massive re-coding of my current logic. The above script is of course just a brief explanation of what my code does, albeit the code for downloading and storing is the same. I'd just hate, if I have to take apart my whole logic and run multiple scripts ... the cross-checking to see which script does what and which xml's should go where would be immense ... or not?

Comment: @Wesley Murch: I trigger this script by cron, every 48 hours, but would like to do so, every 6-12 hours if I can overcome the performance issue ... the script runs for a flat 30 hours + another 1-3 hours to populate my database ... ;(

Comment: should not be a "massive" change, just spawn the scripts with  a link set or id range to check each

Comment: you will want to limit how many you run in parallel  i find 1 per cpu core optimal, any more and they started to get slower as a total - but test your hardware and see. Assuming the machine is not doing anything else.

Comment: Can you just spawn wget in the shell? That sounds like it'd be faster.

Comment: Well, how do I find out how many CPU cores I have or better say, how do I assign a script to a specific CPU core?

Comment: what sort of hosting do you have? i would be surprised if a shared host allowed something like this to run.

Comment: I have my own instances on Amazon as well as couple of VPS that handle some larger databases. the script is run from my most performant VPS and pushes the data to a VPS configured to handle the MySQL database. The front-end is a plain webhoster, but no scripts or databases are run from there, just outputted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bottleneck (most likely) is your curl requests, you can only write to a file after each request is done, there is no way (in a single script) to speed up that process.

I don't know how it all works but you can execute curl requests in parallel: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php.

Maybe you can fetch the data (if memory is available to store it) and then as they complete fill in the data.

Comment: There is nice tutorial about this http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/

Comment: I think I am going to go with this answer. Just waiting a little bit to accept the answer. Perhaps someone may just have an easier solution to my above code...

Answer (score 2):

Just run more script. Each script will download some urls.

You can get more information about this pattern here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

The more script your run the more parallelism you get

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the solution I was looking for. Running multiple scripts in parallel would kill my application logic (or at least I have to rewrite most of my application code to make that work) ... Didn't downvote, but just wanted to clarify ...

Comment: that's how parallelism in big engine works... (i would say almost everyone works) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern also having little php script that you can launch in parallel make their managment much easier

Answer (score 0):

I use on paralel requests guzzle pool ;) ( you can send x paralel request)

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html