# Run PHP foreach in parallel?

Tags: php, parallel-processing

What's the best way to go about running jobs in a foreach in parallel in PHP? Is there a best practice for this? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107339/parallel-processing-in-php-how-do-you-do-it?rq=1

Comment: foreach? what exactly you want to parallelize?

Comment: Each iteration makes a function call that is time consuming (can take several seconds). Was wanting to run the iterations in parallel. I've been able to do this using shell scripting languages but no idea how to do it in PHP (if it can be done).

Comment: @hjpotter92 that thread recommends exec but I've heard people say not to use it

Comment: @user528451 `exec` is fine if you either don't allow user input into the command, or handle it correctly. `exec` is an easy way to fire off a background process without waiting for the result.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: Parallel processing as a language feature isn't supported by php

Answer (score 1):

php doesn't support threading.  The most it offers is forking.

Comment: actually there is https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel for parallel processing in PHP

Comment: @VladyslavStartsev It obviously wasn't a thing at the time of this post 9 years ago.. lol why would you comment on something so old?