# Can I create threads in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does PHP have threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading)

I found this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

But I can't tell if those are threads or processes, I'm confused. They use both words.

In case you have an alternate solution, this is what I need threads for: I want to create a real-time game using web sockets, and I thought of having a single process running in the background, that spawns one thread for each game (or room) on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a wrapper for the C fork() function. It creates processes, not threads. PHP does not support multithreading.

Answer (score 3):

`pcntl_fork` creates a new process. While the word "thread" is used in the documentation, "process" is much more prominent:

> The pcntl_fork() function creates a child process that differs from
>   the parent process only in its PID and PPID.

PHP does not support multithreading (and it cannot assume that the web server itself is multithreaded in general).

Finally, spawning a thread for each anything is a naive approach to scaling that does not scale beyond a certain not-so-late point. I suggest looking into alternate architectures.

Comment: I'm very interested in those alternate architectures, would you mind giving me a hint so I can investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

*** PHP does not support multithreading.