# Pthreads extension installed, but still getting PHP Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found

Tags: php, multithreading, ubuntu, pthreads, php-extension

I have compiled php 5.5.9 with ZTS and phtreads support enabled using this instructions:
http://eddmann.com/posts/compiling-php-5-5-with-zts-and-pthreads-support/

Everything seems alright, extension installed, server restarted, but when I try to use threads, I get an 500 Fatal error: "**PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Thread' not found**"

Could you tell me what I am missing?

*I did add pthreads extension to php.ini

[image]

OS: Ubuntu 10.04

Ty

Comment: Found this question related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081444/how-to-use-pthreads-php-extension-in-ubuntu?rq=1 , but I don't really want to re-compile php, because it takes a bit too long. Isnt there any other solution?

Comment: Faceing same issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the extension is loaded in CLI and not in Apache, IIS, or *insert SAPI here*, it is down to the distribution using a separate mod_php5 for apache, and CLI package for the command line; when a SAPI that requires a shared library is configured, like Apache's mod_php5.so, the library produced by PHP - libphp5.so - is only used for the apache module, the CLI binary does not link against it. This means packagers can distribute php-apache2 and php-cli (for example) packages independently, easy for them. It also means you have two isolated installations of the PHP interpreter, whether you like it or not.

You need to find a package that contains mod_php5.so built in ZTS mode for your distribution.