# Docker php: What are the :zts php images on Docker Hub

Tags: php, docker

As I was looking on: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ I have seen images tagged as: `version_number-zts` or `version_number-zts-alpine` and I am wondering what does the zts indicate on these tags and how much different are from fpm or Apache images?

Comment: Enables zts (Zend Thread Safety) package in PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.requirements.php

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you read one of the docker files https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/1e6f8ba4901a5f3f02f447fd70d4226193e4f24b/7.2-rc/zts/Dockerfile for example.  This has
`ENV PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS --enable-maintainer-zts`

This is used to enable the Zend Thread Safety package in PHP which is used for pthreads.  From the PHP manual(http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.requirements.php)

> pthreads requires a build of PHP with ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) enabled
>   ( --enable-maintainer-zts or --enable-zts on Windows )

Regarding the zts itself is something related to pthreads where you can look for more information on [Php: when to use pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126696/php-when-to-use-pthread)

Comment: And how usefull is zend thread safety. I mean which cases may seem usefull to use zts what is different with zts?

Comment: I think the main thing is that it's a core part of being able to use pthreads, this is the ability to multi-thread PHP.  Normally you have a request which is dealt with by a single thread, multi threading may allow you to spread the processing across multiple processes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126696/php-when-to-use-pthread may give more ideas.