# PHP pthreads and SQLite3

Tags: php, pthreads

## Update

I found this is not an SQLite problem.
Look at this

### Code1

```
<?php
class Test
{
    protected $member;
    public function __construct($member = null)
    {
        $this->member = $member;
        $this->member->text = 'changed text';
    }
}
class Text
{
    public $text = 'this is text';
}
$text = new Text();
$test = new Test($text);
echo $text->text.PHP_EOL;
```

### Output1

```
changed text
```

## Code2

```
<?php
class Test extends Thread  // Difference
{
    protected $member;
    public function __construct($member = null)
    {
        $this->member = $member;
        $this->member->text = 'changed text';
    }
}
class Text
{
    public $text = 'this is text';
}
$text = new Text();
$test = new Test($text);
echo $text->text.PHP_EOL;
```

### Output2

```
this is text
```

And php thread safe is enabled.(from phpinfo)
Is this php malfunction?

## Original

I got some thread problem using SQLite3in php.
code is simple

```
<?php
class Test
{
    protected $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new SQLite3(__DIR__.'/test.db');
        echo $this->db->lastErrorCode().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$test = new Test();
```

`output :` 0

The above code is works good.
But this below code is not working, it just extends Thread

```
<?php
class Test extends Thread
{
    protected $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new SQLite3(__DIR__.'/test.db');
        echo $this->db->lastErrorCode().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$test = new Test();
```

`output :` PHP Warning:  SQLite3::lastErrorCode(): The SQLite3 object has not been correctly initialised in /home/ordinaryparksee/Projects/human/test.php on line 8
Warning: SQLite3::lastErrorCode(): The SQLite3 object has not been correctly initialised in /home/ordinaryparksee/Projects/human/test.php on line 8

What is wrong??

Comment: Not my field, but I guess that `Thread` needs a bit more attention like methods you need to implement?

Comment: And was your sqlite3 built with [`-DTHREADSAFE`](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) enabled?

Comment: Dear @mario. Yes I re-build sqlite3 with option `--enable-threadsafe`. And I checked `-DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1` when make script has compiling. But it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14565559/3333776

> In the manual on the introduction page, it states that any object
>   intended to be manipulated by multiple contexts should extend
>   Stackable, Thread or Worker, like

```
<?php
class Test extends Thread  // Difference
{
    protected $member;
    public function __construct($member = null)
    {
        $this->member = $member;
        $this->member->text = 'changed text';
    }
}
class Text extends Threaded  // Difference2
{
    public $text = 'this is text';
}
$text = new Text();
$test = new Test($text);
echo $text->text.PHP_EOL;
```