# Php pthreads and monolog

Tags: php, pthreads

I cannot use monolog logger inside Thread method run.

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo 'hihi', PHP_EOL;
        $log = new Logger('MyApp');
        $log->pushHandler(
            new StreamHandler('php://stdout', Logger::INFO)
        );
        $log->addInfo("hoho");
        echo 'haha', PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$thread = new MyThread();

if ($thread->start()) {
    $thread->join();
    echo 'hehe', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
hihi
hehe
```

Here [PHP pthreads and SQLite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783282/php-pthreads-and-sqlite3) and here [pthread Thread objects reset their state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564234/pthread-thread-objects-reset-their-state/14565559#14565559) somebody says that I can only use objects inerited from Stackable, Thread or Worker inside my class inherited from Thread. But what if I cannot change Logger class? I cannot use it?

I want to clarify: I cannot use object not inherited from Stackable, Thread or Worker inside class inherited from Thread at all? It is very strange. In other languages I can.

Win 7 x64 Ultimate, php 7 32 bit with thread safety.

Comment: What is your error reporting level ?
Reproducing method ? If I load an empty project and composer require monolog/monolog, I'll be able to reproduce ?
In latest version of monolog I don't see any "addInfo" method nor a __call method ...

Comment: Error reporting level from php.ini: "error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT".
Monolog version from composer.json: "monolog/monolog": "^1.17". I tried $log->info("hoho") but output is the same.

Comment: I've been able to test. I can't reproduce your problem. I created an empty project, composer require monolog stable, and then this script : https://gist.github.com/JesusTheHun/70ae9001d43dc741c4a8
I receive "hihi", "hehe", and a fatal in the middle, meaning it comes from the Thread.
It says the class does not exist. I have no problem if I use monolog outside the Thread. If I include the vendor/autoload.php INSIDE the Thread::run(), it works. It looks like a bug to me, I'll report it.

Comment: Response of Joe : https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/556

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! Can you also say what is your error reporting level? I don't see any errors when I don't include 'vendor/autoload.php' inside Thread::run(), it simply shutdowns without prints any errors.