# Asyncronous job after page elaboration

Tags: php, asynchronous, flush

I have a php page that updates a record in a database and answer to the client with a json string.

After this I need to send some email with an SMTP connection, this may take a few and i don't want to let the client wait for it. I just want the json answer, than I would like to close connection, flush the output and then start the mail sending.
Is it possibile?

Comment: Yes it's very possible. Make the mailing function into a separated PHP file and run that file in background. There're many insights on how to "PHP run process in background" over the Internet.

Comment: You could either run it in a different process or another thread. I described different methods in the answer for another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading/14201579#14201579