# Cakephp 2.X : Run shell command from controller asynchronously

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, asynchronous

I want to run some function asynchronously on specific events. So I want to call a shell command from my controller. I used ShellDispacher but not working in async. Anyone can please suggest me better way for it?

Actually I want to invoke Third Party APIs in my web app as a background process.

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php**

Comment: @ndm Thank you but I want to do this using cakephp 2.x

Comment: Nothing in CakePHP 2.x stops your from invoking the PHP shell execution functions. Read up on [**threading in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading) if that is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

May be start it on cron? In you controller write special value to memcached or Db. Cron job start each minute and check this special value and start work if it present.

Comment: Sorry but I am not a big fan of cron job can you please suggest other way??