# A faster way to retrieve Twitter followers?

Tags: php, twitter

I wrote the following codes which retrieve a user's twitter followers. It works well with users having 150 followers or less (I have tested with several accounts)

However with user's having more than 500 followers, the script takes much time to load, sometimes timing out due to PHP's maximum execution time.

I want to find a better way of doing this and i don't want to edit my php.ini to increase the allowed execution time.

```
<?php
   $cursor = -1;
   $account_from = 'twitter';
   do
   {
     $json = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor='.$cursor.'&screen_name='.$account_from.'');
     $accounts = json_decode($json);

     foreach ($accounts->ids as $account)
      {
        $a[] = $account ; 
      }

      $cursor = $accounts->next_cursor;


    }while ($cursor > 0);


    $n = ceil(count($a) / 100) ; 
    $b = array_chunk($a, 100) ; 



    for($i=0 ; $i<$n ; $i++) {

        $user = ''; 

        for($j=0 ; $j<count($b[$i]) ; $j++) {

                    $user =  $user.$b[$i][$j].',' ;


        }

        $json=file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id='.$user.'') ;
        $fo= json_decode($json);

        foreach ($fo as $key => $jsons) {

             foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {

                     if($key == 'screen_name'){

                             $arr[] = $value;

                    }


            }


        }




    }

    echo "<pre>" ; 
    print_r($arr) ;

?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to only get the followers in small chunks and not the whole thing?

Comment: Of course. You can change the loop conditions to achieve that.

Comment: So you know that it works good with a certain amount.  Check how many followers they have, then if its over that certain amount, pull it down in chunks.  You said a good amount is 150?  Pull down 150 at a time if they have over 150 followers.

Comment: I can't really do that. I am using it for something like jQuery auto-suggest. I have to pull everything at one go.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup)

> You are strongly encouraged to use a POST for larger requests.

I've found that anything over around 50 user IDs needs to use POST.

Answer (score 0):

When the second json request is required for every follower you will not be able to execute the script significant faster, no matter how you optimize the code. The response time of the  HTTP requests are your bottleneck.

The onliest solution then would be to do some [parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101640/patterns-for-php-multi-processes) requests.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with parallel requests. I will look into that.

Comment: I don't recommend the parallel thing.