# parallelize php with exec( )

Tags: php, parallel-processing, exec

I want to parallelize a php program which I use to read some .xml.
I've been googleing and I read about some options:

- fork
- curl
- gearman
- exec

I also red that exec is the best, but I don´t understand how it works. Anyone who can explain it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the manual for each one and determine which one best suits your needs...

Comment: `exec` doesn't parallelize anything because it waits for the spawned process to exit before returning.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101640/patterns-for-php-multi-processes

Answer (score 2):

exec doesn't parallelize. It waits for processing to finish before returning. curl can parallelize using [curl_multi_init()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) and [curl_multi_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). [fork](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) is pretty low level. I don't know [gearman](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php), I've only read the [Basic usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse.php) example, so I cannot tell you anything about it.

Comment: `curl` [can parallelize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php).

Comment: `exec` can run background processes (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#Hcom86329). It can be considered as parallelizing...

Comment: I have been trying to install gearman on my macbook for two hours, but I could'nt. I've tried compiling it myself and installing it with homebrew, but nothing. The thing that annoyes me is that the installation progress looks correct but when I want to run my gearman server (% gearmand -d), the shell outputs 'command not found'.

I think I'll try parallelizing with exec() but I don't know how to do it. If someone could give me a short explanation or a link to a good tutorial or examples, that would be great!

thanks in advance.

Comment: @tmuguet In your link, it's not `exec`, that does the parallelization. It's the command processor. This is not portable, `exec` is not even used on MS-Windows. Moreover, there is no way to capture the output of the program, let alone the execution result. Reason enough for me, to not attribute parallelization to `exec`.