# How to send 1000 push notification at same time to ios devices without using the loop in php

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

How to implpement on below code for send 1000 push notification at same time server to ios deivce using php.

```
 function push_iphone($deviceTokenid,$message){
            $passphrase = '12345';
            $ctx = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
            $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
            if (!$fp)
            return false;
            echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
            // Create the payload body
            $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => $message,
            'message' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'flag' => '0'
            );
            // Encode the payload as JSON
            $payload = json_encode($body);
            //echo $device_token_id;
            // Build the binary notification
            $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceTokenid) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            // Send it to the server
            $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
            if(!$result){
                echo "tst";
                return true;
            }else{ echo "test ";
                return false;
            }
            fclose($fp); 
        }
```

Can any body help me about it.

Comment: Why is it so important to send them at exactly the same time? You can do this by multithreading, but even than, 1000 at exactly the same time  is impossible (emphasis on exactly)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has an answer to this in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html):

> You may establish multiple connections to the same gateway or to
>   multiple gateway instances. If you need to send a large number of
>   remote notifications, spread them out over connections to several
>   different gateways. This improves performance compared to using a
>   single connection: it lets you send the remote notifications faster,
>   and it lets APNs deliver them faster.
>
> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications;
>   don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid
>   connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack. You should
>   leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an
>   extended period of time—for example, if you only send notifications to
>   your users once a day it is ok to use a new connection each day.

By threading your php application you can achieve this at (almost) the same time. Take a look at [Patterns for PHP multi processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101640/patterns-for-php-multi-processes) for a direction which to take to setup forks.

Comment: Please can you provide me some code like my requirement.

Comment: @SandeepVishwakarma I am not going to write your application for you. First try something for yourself. If problems arise from your attempts, post a new question.

Comment: Can be possible to send push billions for device same time ?

Comment: But what to do when one of devices is wrong Apple?? they dont terminate connection they dont provide any response, after the wrong device token, other notifications are just not send...