# Does PHP5 support multi threading?

Tags: php, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one use multi threading in php applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

Does anybody know whether or not PHP5 supports multi threading? If it does, how to implement that?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using php as a module (like in apache), it's not possible. If you use php in CLI, you can use the function [pcntl_fork](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the pcntl extension to fork, please don't.  It creates all sorts of entertaining issues, especially when you're using mod_php.

There are better ways.  Try a work queue, like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).