# Background PHP worker

Tags: php, mysqli, backgroundworker

I have a script that takes a while to process, it has to take stuff from the DB and transfers data to other servers.

At the moment i have it do it immediately after the form is submitted and it takes the time it takes to transfer that data to say its been sent.

I was wondering is the anyway to make it so it does not do the process in front of the client?

I dont want a cron as it needs to be sent at the same time but just not loading with the client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I achieve a task that should be done in thread in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841830/how-can-i-achieve-a-task-that-should-be-done-in-thread-in-php)

Comment: more related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=background+process+php

Comment: and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gearman+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. [Exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php.) the PHP script that does the DB work from your webpage but do not wait for the output of the exec. Be **VERY** careful with this, don't blindly accept any input parameters from the user without sanitising them. I only mention this as an option, I would never do it myself.
2. Have your DB updating script running all the time in the backgroun, polling for something to happen that triggers its update. Say, for example, it could be checking to see if /tmp/run.txt exists and will start DB update if it does. You can then create run.txt from your webpage and return without waiting for a response.
3. Create your DB update script as a daemon.

Comment: whats needed to make a daemon? is the any requirements to the server needed?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can take a look at:

How much data are you transferring, and by transfer is it more like a copy-and-paste the data only, or are you inserting the data from your db into the destination server and then deleting the data from your source?

You can try analyzing your SQL to see if there's any room for optimization.

Then you can check your php code as well to see if there's anything, even the slightest, that might aid in performing the necessary tasks faster.

Where are the source and destination database servers located (in terms of network and geographically, if you happen to know) and how fast the source and destination servers are able to communicate through the net/network?