# Parallel, multiple SOAP requests/connections?

Tags: php, soap, parallel-processing

I'm running the following code:

```
<?php

$i=0;

// connection credentials and settings
$location = 'https://url.com/';
$wsdl = $location.'?wsdl';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

// create client resource - connection
$client = new Client($location, $wsdl, $username, $password);

// do stuff
while($i<10)
    {
      $client-­‐>doStuff();
      echo $client‐>response();
      $i++;
    }

?>
```

Separately:

```
<?php

public function doStuff() {
$this->response = $this->srv()->doStuff(array('stuff' => $this->get('stuff')));
return $this;
}

public function __construct($location, $wsdl, $username, $password, $proxyHost = NULL, $proxyPort = NULL) {

if(is_null($proxyHost) || is_null($proxyPort)) $connection = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('login' => $username, 'password' => $password));
else $connection = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('login' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'proxy_host' => $proxyHost, 'proxy_port' => $proxyPort));
$connection->__setLocation($location);
$this->connection = $connection;
return $this->connection;
}

public function srv() {
return $this->connection;
}

?>
```

I wanted to change this to run multiple connections, possibly in parallel, although I am not familiar enough with SOAP to understand how to go about this.

ie: While it's running $client-­‐>doStuff(); in the loop, I'd like it to run another resource / connection of the next iteration before the other finishes.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: I would look into multi-threading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Comment: @Phill Pafford: Thanks! Looks like what I was after, but no idea how to adjust the above to accomplish what is shown in the example [link](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254) as it uses fsock. Any suggestions or examples in using SOAP? Thank you again.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#64094

Comment: @Phill Pafford: Looking more like it.. basically fsockopen, run SOAP connection, then close. How could I adjust the above code to fit in with the fsockopen example? (any help with cut and paste code in the right areas would be VERY appreciated) Sorry, extremely new to this. Thanks!!

Comment: @Phill Pafford: Please also add anything further to your own answer so I can accept your solution :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is a functional language the script waits until `$client-­‐>doStuff();` is finished each time in while loop.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So what could I possibly do to speed up each 'doStuff' function? I thought multi-threading would be the only way..

Comment: as Phill Pafford said, check for multithreading and activate the wsdl caching.

Comment: Not a problem. I have updated the original code which may give you a better insight into what I am dealing with, in regards to the resource/connection. You still suggest multithreading and wsdl caching?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Multi-Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications), also [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#64094) might help.

So using [this example](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254) you might consider the JobStartAsync() to represent each SOAP request.

PSEUDO Code:

```
while($i<10) {
    JobStartAsync($client = new Client($location, $wsdl, $username, $password),$client­‐>doStuff());
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Execute SOAP using cURL like this:

[Execute SOAP using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017722/execute-soap-using-curl)

And use this PHP class providing an interface for running multiple concurrent CURL requests:

https://github.com/recuweb/ParallelCurl