# Php SOAP client to read from Orange M2M

Tags: php, soap

I am wondering if there are any guides anywhere or anyone can help with using a PHP SOAP client to connect to the Orange M2M server in order to display SMS messages on a web page. I am quite stuck with where to even begin with this problem and after googling around I have nothing to make a start with...here is my challenge.

I would like to use a PHP SOAP client to connect to the Orange M2M SMS SOAP server and access it using my username/password, I would want to then use this to look at the messages on there to read and display them in a web report. I don't know where to even begin with this, I have looked at Php SOAP clients but nothing about using Orange M2M itself which has thrown me.

Any help is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried: [Orange M2M Support](http://www.orange-obs.exvn.com/forms/m2m.cfm)

Comment: Yes I have and am yet to receive a reply, do you have any knowledge of the area?

Answer (score 0):

As you are wanting to use a PHP client, I would use PHP cURL functions for SOAP. Someone posted a similar problem and a cURL solution was provided, see [Execute SOAP using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017722/execute-soap-using-curl)... although this was for POST you would do something similar for GET. Either way you will receive a server response through the "curl_exec($ch)" function. I suggest looking at the cURL function reference on PHP help for more detail.

This basically retrieves information from the server. There are various methods to then display this information on a webpage (e.g. one method would be through an "echo" command).