# PHP multi-threading / multi http requests

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, http, shell

I need to create a script that goes through a few thousand websites and fetch data such as headers, ips, response code and also some other stuff for fingerprinting (college schoolwork).

How does multithreading or multiple http requests work if the script needs to go through all the thousands of website, this would take ages and ages.

Can anyone share their knowledge?

Thanks

Comment: Multithreading kinda requires skills.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Comment: You're question is vague and/or badly worded. 'How does multithreading or multiple http requests work....' Do you mean how should go abou implementing it or do you realyl want an explanation of something which should be covered within the first week of any course on computers?

Comment: Is it possible yes/no does it require alot of skill. thats all, no need to get out of topic

Comment: Why do you need multiple threads for it ? You can send HTTP HEAD requests which are faster than GET , despite your script going over 'thousands' of websites  I don't see how this takes ages!