# simultaneously run foreach results php

Tags: php, multithreading, for-loop

I pull results from my database, with a while I process each result. Now I would like to run all these results simultaneously. Is this possible with php?

Below I added a example code, I would like to have that for each result the query is executed simultaneously without waiting for the other results to be completed before going to next.

```
 while ($accountdata = mysql_fetch_array($qaccountdata)) 
 { 
   $un  = $accountdata['email'];
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO log (id, email, item,height, stamp) VALUES ('', '$un','something','', '" . strtotime('now') . "')");              
 }
```

What about something like this? script.php contains the process.

```
<?php

$q = 1;

$mh = curl_multi_init();

while ($accountdata = mysql_fetch_array($qaccountdata)) {
        $a = $accountdata['email'];
        $ch.$q = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch.$q, CURLOPT_URL, 'script.php?id='.$a);
        curl_setopt($ch.$q, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch.$q);
        $q++;
    }

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch.$q);
curl_multi_close($mh);  



?>
```

Script.php

```
 if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
     $_GET['id'] = $un
     //rest of code
  }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Comment: Can it be done with?


     `$count = amount of results

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 1)
    {
         while ($accountdata = mysql_fetch_array($qaccountdata)) 
         { 
         }
    }`

Comment: NO. `mysql_fetch_array($qaccountdata)` will block your program until he ends.

Comment: Updated my first post

Answer (score 4):

**Avoid doing SQL queries within a loop**

A common mistake is placing a SQL query inside of a loop. This results in multiple round trips to the database, and significantly slower scripts. In the example below, you can change the loop to build a single SQL query and insert all of your users at once.

```
foreach ($userList as $user) {
  $query = 'INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name) VALUES("' . $user['first_name'] . '", "' . $user['last_name'] . '")';
  mysql_query($query);
  }
```

Produces:

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name) VALUES("John", "Doe")
```

Instead of using a loop, you can combine the data into a single database query.

```
$userData = array();
foreach ($userList as $user) {
    $userData[] = '("' . $user['first_name'] . '", "' . $user['last_name'] . '")';
 }
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name) VALUES' . implode(',', $userData);
mysql_query($query);
```

Produces:

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name) VALUES("John", "Doe"),("Jane", "Doe")...
```

Make yourself and your server a favor, read the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/insert.html) and some tips [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php).