# Symfony2: pthreads produces blank page

Tags: php, multithreading, symfony

I'm trying to use the extension php_pthreads with Symfony2.
I set up a simple controller:

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SimpleThread extends \Thread {

    public function run() {
        sleep(100);
    }
}

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $simpleThread = new SimpleThread();
        $simpleThread->start();
        return $this->render('TestTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => "World"));
    }
}
```

And it just gives me a blank page (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET). I have nothing to try to fix it since there is no error, I don't know how to debug this.

When I try to run this simple test code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501449/3070307) outside of Symfony, it works fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**
Ok two things:

```
sleep(100);
```

Sleeps for 100 seconds... I miss-typed usleep.

Second, the Symfony cache is messing with thread execution apprently, disabling it fixed it (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/debugging.html).

The only remaining problem is the render function does nothing, I'm not even sure it's called.

Comment: Did yoy turn on `display_errors` in `php.ini`? Also, check out the `error_reporting`...

Comment: error_reporting = E_ALL, display_errors = On, so yes they are.

Comment: Pull from git, there was a bug in repo for a few days ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins pull pthreads or Symfony?

Comment: @LordSk pull pthreads I meant ...