# Multi processing a PHP script?

Tags: php, multithreading

I have a PHP-script that does five different API-request. The script is slow because every API-request "has to wait for the previous to execute". All the API-requests push an array. The scripts echoes out the whole array in the end.

How can I speed up the script using multi processing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using [`curl_multi_init()`](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)?  I've never used it, but it looks like it could help here.

Comment: ^, but make sure that the APIs are all from a different host. You might be violating rate limits if you attempt to access an API too quickly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

Answer (score 1):

## Multi-threading is certainly an option

```
<?php
class Fetcher extends Thread {
    public function __construct(Threaded $shared, $page) {
        $this->shared = $shared;
        $this->page   = $page;
    }

    public function run() {
        $data = file_get_contents($this->page);
        if ($data) {
            $this->shared[$this->page] = $data;
        }
    }

    protected $shared;
    protected $page;
}

$start   = microtime(true);
$shared  = new Threaded();
$thread  = 0;
$threads = [];

while ($thread++<8) {
    $threads[$thread] = new Fetcher($shared, sprintf(
        "http://www.google.com/?q=%s", md5(mt_rand())));
    $threads[$thread]->start();
}

foreach ($threads as $thread)
    $thread->join();

printf("Complete in %.3f seconds:\n", microtime(true)-$start);
foreach ($shared as $page => $data) 
    printf("\t%s contained %d bytes\n", $page, strlen($data));
?>
```

I have used nonsense google searches, but the principles are the same.

- Start with the `README.md` on github: http://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads
- Keep the manual close by all the time: http://php.net/pthreads

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are calling these APIs over HTTP, you can use multi-curl to run all five API calls simultaneously.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

There are several libraries that wrap the PHP functions to make this easier.  An example from here:  https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl

```
<?php
  $mc = EpiCurl::getInstance();
  $yahoo = $mc->addURL('http://www.yahoo.com/');
  $google = $mc->addURL('http://www.google.com/');

  echo "The response code for Yahoo! was {$yahoo->code} and Google was {$google->code}";
?>
```

Comment: The requests are not executed using curl. Simple PHP is used. I do q request and then a grab the result from a JSON array from the "API host".

Comment: @SecretCoder It sure sounds like you're using HTTP in some way to me...  If you're not, this isn't possible.  PHP isn't multithreaded, and all of the libraries to hack such functionality in place are similar to multicurl in how they work.

Comment: http://pastie.org/8991839

This is an example of how I do 2 different API calls. Is you script going to work Brad?

Comment: @SecretCoder It can, but you would need to rework TwitterAPIExchange.  And, you might need to use multi-curl manually since you need more control over the headers.

Comment: that sounds very complicated... I am searching for something that would separate parst of the script and run them at the same tim. Can I do different files for every API-call and run them att the same time in a new script?

Comment: @SecretCoder Yes, you could definitely go that route... and call your own scripts with multi-curl.  For what it's worth, modifying TwitterAPIExchange probably wouldn't be too difficult.  I haven't seen the code, but there's probably a place where you see `curl_exec()`.  This effectively gets replaced with `curl_multi_exec()`, but some other modifications would still be needed.  If you want to split your current code out into multiple scripts, and call those scripts with my original suggested php-multi-curl code, that would solve your problem in a simple way.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using cURL to fetch data, you should look into https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl which allows you make parallel curl requests.

There is also an example at https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl/blob/master/test.php which is pretty straightforward and explains the usage pretty good.

Comment: Consider [Artax](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax) for async/parallel processing without threading.