# Send multiple numbers SMS requests in one second PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, pthreads

I'm trying to send SMS using an API. It is sending almost one SMS per second but i want to send multiple SMS in one second using multithreading/pthreads in PHP. How is it possible or how can i send multiple SMS request asynchronously to API server from my end at least time.

```
//Threads Class
class MThread extends Thread {

public $data;
public $result;

  public function __construct($data){
    $this->data = $data;
   }

  public function run() {

    foreach($this->data as $dt_res){

        // Send the POST request with cURL 
        $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dt_res['to']); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        $res = curl_exec($ch); 
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        $this->result = $http_code;
        /**/
       }
    }
}

// $_POST['data'] has multi arrays
$request = new MThread($_POST['data']);

if ($request->start()) {
  $request->join();
  print_r($request->result);
}
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: See: [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

Comment: @Wiiliam I'm using this PThreads but it didn't affect or didn't working as required.

Answer (score 6):

You don't necessarily need to use threads to send multiple HTTP requests asynchronously. You can use non-blocking I/O, multicurl is suitable in this case. There are some HTTP clients with multicurl support.
Example (using [Guzzle 6](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html)):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$requestGenerator = function() use ($client) {
    $uriList = ['https://www.google.com', 'http://amazon.com', 'http://github.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com'];
    foreach ($uriList as $uri) {
        $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri);
        $promise = $client->sendAsync($request);
        yield $promise;
    }
};

$concurrency = 4;
\GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit($requestGenerator(), $concurrency, function(\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response $response) {
    var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
}, function(\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
})->wait();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you make a foreach into the run() ? When you do that, that exactly like a simple function, no multithreading.

### So, how to use multithreading with pthread ?

Here is the solution at your problem:

```php
$thread = array();
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $index => $data) {
    $thread[$index] = new MThread($data);
    $thread[$index]->start();
}
```

You should be able to understand your error with this code.

Just delete your foreach into your run() function and use my code and it's will work.

Comment: Yep, maybe this is the reason why @Raheel's multi-threading with PThreads is not working

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use something like Beanstalk with multiple workers.

Comment: how Beanstalk works any example please and how to install it?

Comment: I listened and looked something abour php gearman thats seems intrusting. I want to use gearman on my local system windows 7 32 bit xampp and php 5.4. any idea for this please.

Comment: Sorry, no, I no longer use Windows.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i start worker automatically when client executed or any other idea to start worker automatically or through code?