# PHP Equivalent of setInterval Function

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have a long running PHP script that looks something like this:

```
$myClass->myFunction('this takes 30 minutes to run');
```

I want to send a heartbeat every 30 seconds during the running of `myFunction()` to alert my application that the script is still running and did not fail.

In JavaScript, I can achieve this with `setInterval()`.  I want to be able to do the same thing in PHP.  Perhaps with a custom `setInterval()` function that looks like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $myClass->addHeartbeat("still running");    
}, 30000);
```

Is this possible given the synchronous nature of PHP?

Comment: Use [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: You cannot really do this with javascript considering it's single threaded.

Comment: do not use `sleep()`.. that pauses the whole script..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Comment: @Barmar: good sh*t. I've been looking for this example.

Comment: Using an event loop, you can create a timer event that gets executed every X seconds. Using [LibEV](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) and [PHP extension](https://github.com/m4rw3r/php-libev) to interact with it, the code becomes pretty trivial. It's much easier than threading example, and since you already have a daemon - I assume that using the event loop would be quite easy.

Answer (score -1):

There isnt any easy way of doing this, but since you have a long running php script you can do something like this, assuming you have a main loop.:

```
while($running) { // long running main loop

    if(time() % 30 == 0) {
        $myClass->addHeartbeat("still running");
    }
    // your long running phpscript code
}
```

Comment: But this will never execute the rest of the code in the script, it will just get stuck in this loop.