# Is multithreading possible in php?

Tags: php, web

Now we are working on a small web application we started this with php but we have some requirement to create some threads in php, what are advantage and disadvantage of PHP threads . how php handling synchronisation for common data.

my requirement are given bellow

1. User can create some background jobs.
2. in each thread we want to create some child threads.
3. in run time thread properties can be configurable

Comment: What about the manual ? http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Comment: @Frederik.L ya i read that manual .. and i searched lot of blogs, i got only it possible, but no real world performance or nothing regarding PHP threads.

Comment: What do you mean by performance? What are your requirements? There are lots (lots!) of tutorials out there which deal with php threads.

Comment: Too broad IMO. This question is about any information anyone could give about anything related to threads. There is no right answer neither complete answer to this question, hence I'd recommend improving the question so it actually asks something that can be answered.

Comment: @davidgiga1993 can u share some links ,i am not a php developer ,for a particular requirement we choose php

Comment: Google "php threading tutorial". First entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Comment: @davidgiga1993 i seen lot of posts php threads are not working properly etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, Pthread library is what you need to use.

`For windows`:

You will have to install some dlls

`For linux`:

You might need to recompile php using zts because by default it is disabled or not installed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use threads in PHP.
The advantages/disadvantages are the same as in any other programming language.

Take a look at the manual for more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php