# Non blocking up/downloads using ssh2_sftp

Tags: php, sftp, nonblocking, ssh2-sftp

How can I use non-blocking up/downloads with `ssh2_sftp_` (like with `ftp_nb_put`/`ftp_nb_get`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP SSH2 functions do not support non-blocking operation. Neither [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) does.

---

But you can move your download code to a separate thread using the [`Thread` PECL class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php).

For an example see:
[How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70855/850848)

---

Or you can upload the file in chunks.
See https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp#positional-control