# Non-blocking SFTP/FTPS uploads with PHP?

Tags: php, ftp, sftp, ftps

PHP has an function for uploading files non-blocking ftp_nb_put(),
but i would like to know if non-blocking ftp uploads is possible with sftp & ftps.

If not, what other languages provide non-blocking ftp uploads for sftp/ftps ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about the language, but having a library that supports non-blocking operations.

---

The PHP SSH2 functions do not support non-blocking operation. Neither [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) does.

But you can move your download code to a separate thread using the [`Thread` PECL class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php).

For an example see:
[How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70855/850848)

---

Or spawn an external process for the transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Non-blocking operations are not about languages, but about particular software components. You can have non-blocking transfer in any language given that you have the proper components. In .NET, Java, Delphi there are plenty of such components.

In PHP you can [spawn an external process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process) which will perform the upload under the hood.