# PHP multi-threading

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets

I want to perform multiple for loops at once. For loop consists of socket operations. I want to send request and get response using socket. Current problem is that first of all First for loop executes and then second one. How do I perform simultaneously ? Please explain with example. This is the code :

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}  

for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}  

for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}  

for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}  
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}  
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}  
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}  
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}  
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
}
```

?>

How can I perform all of them at once ?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? A simple Google search will give you quite some answers. Including this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Comment: I tried. But I don't want to use OOP approach.

Comment: Why not use OOP if that is a simple and straightforward way to handle your problem?

Comment: I'm on shared hosting. I don't think I will able to install pthreads.

Comment: Have you asked? Is it not already there perhaps?

Comment: Multi-threading is wholly unnecessary ... research non-blocking I/O ...

Answer (score 1):

Сreate bash script with calls to php scrips inside.

**bash-start.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    /bin/ps -auwx | /usr/bin/grep  custon-name-php-file.php | /usr/bin/awk  '{print $2}' | /usr/bin/xargs kill -9

    for i in `seq 1 15`;  # 15 - count threads
    do
       echo $i
        /usr/sbin/daemon custon-name-php-file.php $i
    done
```

**custon-name-php-file.php**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$thread = $_SERVER['argv'][1];

for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
{
  //Soecket operations
  echo $thread."). ".$i.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Will it run on background ?

Comment: What is daemon btw ??

Comment: it's for FreeBSD. You need to find background tool for your server's os. What os do you use on server?