# Popen doesn't work

Tags: php, popen

It seems that on my server the `popen()` doesn't work at all. I access `test.php` via browser and the files `postt1.php` and `postt2.php` do not get executed. The `article1.txt` and `article2.txt` files are not written. All the files are in the same directory.

What could be the problem?

In file `test.php` I have:

```
<?php
$pipe1 = popen('postt1.php', 'w');
$pipe2 = popen('postt2.php', 'w');

pclose($pipe1);
pclose($pipe2);
echo "end"; 
?>
```

Inside files `postt1.php` I have:

```
<?php
 $tosave =  "Hello there";

 $file = fopen("article1.txt","w");
 fwrite($file,$tosave);
 fclose($file);
 echo $tosave;
 echo "<br>done";
 ?>
```

and in the `postt2.php` I have the same thing except that I write to file `article2.txt`.

Comment: popen requires a command as first parameter, you are just passing `postt1.php`, i would say something like `php postt1.php`. OR use `include` if you want to execute those(postt1 & postt2) file.

Comment: Are you sure - there is no another argument in popen on this page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Answer (score 0):

`postt1.php` end `postt2.php` need [shebang tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (#!) and execute permissions.

Add the  shebang tag by telling the file where the PHP interpreter is on the first line in the file (before the `<?php`!). Best practices dictates that you should access the interpreter via the `env` command:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env php

<?php
 $tosave =  "Hello there";

 $file = fopen("article1.txt","w");
 fwrite($file,$tosave);
 fclose($file);
 echo $tosave;
 echo "<br>done";
 ?>
```

You can also use a shebang that points directly to `php`: `#!/usr/bin/php`. But this is less portable accross systems.

---

You must also ensure that both files have executable premissions:

`$ chmod +x posttl.php`