# How to use multi-threading in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am scraping a site using goutte to get some of amount of data. But it's making the site slow. So I want to use multi-threading How can I do multi-threading in laravel framework?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read about [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please, also note that SO is not  a public tutorial site. Thanks.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Answer (score 1):

You can use Queues in [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues). It does the same job it run the code in background.