# PHP Thread in Yii2

Tags: php, multithreading, yii, yii2

How can I run a function in a different thread in PHP?
I searched on Google, but I didn't find anything which works.

A simple example would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

Comment: @AlexandreT This is not duplicate. Question posted Yii related multithread. I have done multithreading in core php Which you have mentioned duplicate. Unable to do it in Yii1 or Yii2.