# I need to implement a wait timer INSIDE of a PHP React websocket event loop (perhaps multithreading?)

Tags: php, event-loop, reactphp

I have a websocket application that I am building a game on, built on Ratchet which uses the React event loop. At the start of this script, I have already figured out how to implement a periodictimer, to send a pulse to the game every second, and then execute ticks and combat rounds. This works great.

However, I have recently realized that I will also need to add the ability to "lag" clients, or pause execution in a function. For example, if a player is stunned, or I want an NPC to wait for 1.5 seconds before replying to a trigger for a more "realistic" conversational feel.

Is this functionality built into the react library, or is it something that I am going to have to achieve through other means? After some research, it looks like maybe pthreads is what I may be looking for, see this question/answer: [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

To be more clear with what I am trying to achieve, take this code as an example:

```
    function onSay($string)
{
    global $world;

    $trigger_words = array(
        'hi',
        'hello',
        'greetings'
    );

    $triggered = false;

    foreach($trigger_words as $trigger_word)
    {
        if(stristr($string, $trigger_word))
        {
            $triggered = true;
        }
    }

    if($triggered)
    {
        foreach($world->players as $player)
        {
            if($player->pData->in_room === $this->mobile->in_room)
            {
                sleep(1);
                $this->toChar($player, $this->mobile->short . " says '`kOh, hello!``'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, as the sleep(1) function will halt the entire server process.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Update: My server script:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'src/autoload.php';
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use React\Socket\Server as Reactor;
use React\EventLoop\Factory as LoopFactory;;

$world = new WorldInterface();

class Server implements MessageComponentInterface
{   
    public function __construct(React\EventLoop\LoopInterface $loop) 
    {
        $update = new Update();
        $update->doTick();

        $loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function() 
        {
            $this->doBeat();    
        });
    }

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $ch) 
{
    global $world;
    $world->connecting[$ch->resourceId] = $ch;
    $ch->CONN_STATE = "GET_NAME";
    $ch->pData = new stdClass();
    $ch->send("Who dares storm our wayward path? ");
}

public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $ch, $args) 
{   
    if($ch->CONN_STATE == "CONNECTED")
    {
        $ch->send("> " . $args . "\n");
        $interpreter = new Interpreter($ch);
        $interpreter->interpret($args);
    }
    else
    {
        $ch->send($args);
        $login = new Login($ch, $args);
        $login->start();
    }

}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $ch) 
{
    global $world;

    if(isset($ch->pData->name))
    {
        if(isset($world->players[$ch->pData->name]))
        {
            echo "Player {$ch->pData->name} has disconnected\n";
            unset($world->players->{$ch->pData->name});
        }
    }

    if(isset($world->connecting->{$ch->resourceId}))
    {
        echo "Connection " . $ch->resourceId . " has disconnected.";
        unset($world->connecting->{$ch->resourceId});
    }
}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) 
{
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    $conn->close();
}

public function doBeat()
{
    global $world;
    ++$world->beats;

    foreach($world->process_queue as $trigger_beat => $process_array)
    {
        // if the beat # that the function should fire on is less than,
        // or equal to the current beat, fire the function.
        if($trigger_beat <= $world->beats)
        {
            foreach($process_array as $process)
            {
                $class = new $process->class();
                call_user_func_array(array($class, $process->function), $process->params);
            }

            // remove it from the queue
            unset($world->process_queue[$trigger_beat]);
        }
        // else, the beat # the function should fire on is greater than the current beat, 
        // so break out of the loop.
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if($world->beats % 2 === 0)
    {
        $update = new Update();
        $update->doBeat();
    }
}
}

$loop = LoopFactory::create();
$socket = new Reactor($loop);
$socket->listen(9000, 'localhost');
$server = new IoServer(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Server($loop))),   $socket, $loop);
$server->run();
```

Comment: Any reason why timer doesn't work for you? like `$this->loop->addTimer(1, function() use {$player} {$this->toChar($player, $this->mobile->short . " says '`kOh, hello!``'");})`

Comment: That would be perfect, except that I don't think I have access to the loop by the time I get input from the user. I have updated my question with my server startup script. Is there a way to get access to $loop in the onMessage function?

Comment: Sure you have. You don't receive a byte from clients before you open a socket, and `$loop` must exist at this point, as socket requires it in the constructor. The *My server script* part is a mess tbh.

Comment: You didn't really help, you just told me it was possible then insulted me..

Comment: Welp! I take it back, you did actually help. I somehow didn't realize I could just store $loop as a property, but that does work. Hopefully this makes the startup script less of a "mess" ;) If you want to put that as an answer I'll be happy to mark it correct. Thank you!

Comment: Did I? Please accept my deepest apologies if so. Believe me it wasn't intentional. If I find couple of hours to write a POC I will put it as an answer. For the time being, I only can assure you that the loop exists at the time when you receive any message from a client.

Comment: Yes you were right! And no need to apologize, my server script probably does look like a mess from an outsider honestly. I am not sure why I thought I could only use the loop inside my constructor, setting it as a property allows me to access it from anywhere, which opens up a lot of doors. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I'm going to assume that because this is still unanswered there is no "easy" solution baked into the react event loop, though I would love to be wrong about that. Until then, I figured I would post my solution.

Note: *I have no idea what the implications of doing this are. I have no idea how scalable it is. It is untested in a live environment with multiple processes and players.*

I think it's a decent solution however. My particular game is geared toward a playerbase of maybe 20 - 30, so I think the only problem I might face is if a bunch of queued actions fire on the exact same second.

To the code!

The first thing I did (a while ago) was add a periodic timer on server startup:

```
public function __construct(React\EventLoop\LoopInterface $loop) 
{
    $update = new Update();
    $update->doTick();

    $loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function() 
    {
        $this->doBeat();    
    });
}
```

I also have some global variables on my 'world' class:

```
// things in the world
public $beats = 0;
public $next_tick = 45;
public $connecting = array();
public $players = array();
public $mobiles = array();
public $objects = array();
public $mobs_in_rooms = array();
public $mobs_in_areas = array();
public $in_combat = array(
    'mobiles' => array(),
    'players' => array()
);
public $process_queue;
```

Note **beats** and **process_queue**.

My doBeat() function looks like this:

```
public function doBeat()
{
    global $world;
    ++$world->beats;

    foreach($world->process_queue as $trigger_beat => $process_array)
    {
        // if the beat # that the function should fire on is less than,
        // or equal to the current beat, fire the function.
        if($trigger_beat <= $world->beats)
        {
            foreach($process_array as $process)
            {
                $class = new $process->class();
                call_user_func_array(array($class, $process->function), $process->params);
            }

            // remove it from the queue
            unset($world->process_queue[$trigger_beat]);
        }
        // else, the beat # the function should fire on is greater than the current beat, 
        // so break out of the loop.
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    print_r(array_keys($world->process_queue));

    if($world->beats % 2 === 0)
    {
        $update = new Update();
        $update->doBeat();
    }
}
```

Now, on my global "World" object, I have a couple other functions:

```
function addToProcessQueue($process_obj)
{
    //adds the process object to an array of the beat #
    //when it should be triggered on process_queue.

    $this->process_queue[(int)$process_obj->trigger_beat][] = $process_obj;
    ksort($this->process_queue);
}

function createProcessObject($array)
{
    $process_obj = new stdClass();

    if(isset($array['function']))
    {
        $process_obj->function = $array['function'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All process requests must define a function to call defined as a key named 'function' on the array you pass.";
    }

    if(isset($array['class']))
    {
        $process_obj->class = $array['class'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All process requests must define a class to call defined as a key named 'class' on the array you pass.";
    }

    if(isset($array['params']))
    {
        $process_obj->params = $array['params'];
    }
    else
    {
        $process_obj->params = array();
    }

    if(isset($array['char']))
    {
        $process_obj->char = $array['char'];
    }
    else
    {
        $process_obj->char = false;
    }

    if(isset($array['trigger_beat']) && is_numeric($array['trigger_beat']))
    {
        $process_obj->trigger_beat = $array['trigger_beat'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All process requests must define a trigger_beat. \n"
        . "Use world->beats to get current beat and add your wait time onto it. \n"
                . "Trigger beat MUST be an integer. \n";
    }

    $this->addToProcessQueue($process_obj);
}
```

Now to add a process to the queue, here is my new mobile "onSay()" command:

```
function onSay($string)
{
    global $world;

    $trigger_words = array(
        'hi',
        'hello',
        'greetings'
    );

    $triggered = false;

    foreach($trigger_words as $trigger_word)
    {
        if(stristr($string, $trigger_word))
        {
            $triggered = true;
        }
    }

    if($triggered)
    {
        $process_array = array(
            'trigger_beat' => $world->beats + 2,
            'function' => 'toRoom',
            'class' => 'PlayerInterface',
            'params' => array($this->mobile->in_room, $this->mobile->short . " says '`kOh, hello!``'")
        );

        $world->createProcessObject($process_array);
    }
}
```

So, if the mobile hears "hi", "hello" or "greetings", the "toRoom" function (which sends a string to every character in the same room) will be added to the process queue and will fire 2 seconds from when the original function was executed.

I hope all that makes sense and if anyone knows of a better way to accomplish stuff like this in php and inside an event loop please answer / comment. I'm not marking this as "correct" as like I said above, I have no idea how efficient it will be in production.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`addTimer`](https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop/blob/204ed4fe574774b1cf7b90282ee12479dfbd5d6b/src/LoopInterface.php#L57) like you did with `addPeriodicTimer`. If you want to work with promises, you can create a helper promise that resolves just after your pause time.

Amp (another event loop implementation) has [`Amp\Pause`](https://github.com/amphp/amp/blob/72378e2b82d9f1dee6b93de2bee8aa138e7f67e1/lib/Pause.php) which does exactly that. Maybe you can use that as inspiration if you want to implement a promise as mentioned.