# running function in parallel in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel, parallel-processing

I got an issue on laravel 5.1 in performance,

```
public static function test($keyword)
{

//fun1

$x = $bh -> getASearch($keyword);

$output['A'] = $bh -> gNOR($a, $nor);

//fun2

$y = $bh -> getBSearch($keyword);

$output['B'] = $bh -> gNOR($b, $nor);

//fun3

$z = $bh -> getCSearch($keyword);

$output['C'] = $bh -> gNOR($c, $nor);

}
```

I want to run this code for fun1, fun2 and fun3 in parallel in order to reduce the load time

Comment: multi threading in php: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

Comment: I tried with pcntl_fork() and pthreads , but no accurate results  it still executes the script in parallelly