# how to repeat in for with out wait respond PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, curl, exec

i have vps and need some help with case ,
in crontab there are command run every minute

```
* * * * * /usr/share/html/mysite/do.php
```

in do.php file there are some thing like this

```
<?php
    class job
    {   
        function fetch()
        {
            global $curl;

            for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
                $res = $curl->get('http://www.****.com/data.php');
                if($res == 'OK') {
                    return 'OK';
                }
                sleep(60);  
            }
        }       
    }   
    $job = new job();

    $value = 5;
    for($i=0;$i<$value;$i++) {  
        $job->fetch();  
    }
?>
```

now my problem in`$job->fetch();` i want Repeat five times with out wait
but my problem its wait respond from `function fetch`  maybe 1 min or max 4 min
i need to run this job 5 times in same .
note: i can use any thing curl exec etc...

Comment: i don't understand this code because it's not indented

Comment: It's very simple and clear,
i want to run $jobe->featch(); 5 times in same second

Comment: Are you just want to call the page 5 times or are you also need the return value?

Comment: only call page 5 times

Answer (score 0):

You can't run 5 functions at the same time in php, it's a synchrone language and monothreaded(can be tweeked with libraries [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications) .
If your function fetch take 1 minute to run you have to wait 1 minute before the next turn of the loop and the next call to fetch.

Comment: how ti install in centos php 7 ?

Comment: You really need to explain your issue better to except better answers. I d'ont understand what you want to achieve here, run 5 time fetch in parallel, or make the function fetch run faster ?