# PHP flush is not working as expected (don't output immediately)

Tags: php

I tried to use buffer flush to deliver output to user's browsers and continue with another time-consuming task. But flush() seems no working as expected.

I have set those values in my nginx:
    gzip  off;
    proxy_buffering  off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 1k;
    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
    fastcgi_buffers 128 1k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1k;

centos7.6, php7.2, laravel5.7

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();

echo view('dataChart', $this->calc())->render();

ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

sleep(15);  //<- here's the problem, this 15s is supposed to have no effect. Page is expected to show immediately.

// Here's some heavy task
```

I want to know why this sleep(15) still has effect on page loading.

The response is still delyed for 15s.

Comment: Here it says that concurrent programming is possible using HTTP requests as Asynchronous calls https://stackoverflow.com/a/1079624/10634638

Comment: Check your title, do you really mean "as expected"?