# Pthreads vs Parallel for infinite loops on PHP

Tags: php, parallel-processing, pthreads

I was looking for a way to perform multi-threads on PHP and came across the pthreads PHP API, which I think could be easy to implement (however I'll have to find out how to install the PHP version with ZTS support for Debian).

The thing is that when I was looking at the pthreads php.net documentation I found this:

> Tip Consider using parallel instead.

Which I didn't know about.

My goal is to get a list of items and for each one, open a websocket that listens for certain updates forever. So the thread should be there forever and if killed, or stopped, or so, it should be restarted (however I think I can handle this externally).

I'm not sure which one would be the most appropriate for this situation. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first thing to say is that there is nothing in the description of your application that demands the use of threads, it would seem what you really want is asynchronous concurrency: Asynchronous concurrency is typically used to increase the throughput of I/O bound code, by eliminating unnecessary waiting. Parallel concurrency is typically used to increase the throughput of CPU bound code, by utilising more cores.

There are a few good frameworks for implementing non-blocking I/O in PHP, the one I would recommend is [amphp](http://amphp.org).

Of course, I may not have a full description of your application, so onto the subject of pthreads: [It is made obsolete by parallel](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/929), new projects should use parallel.

*Disclaimer: I wrote pthreads and parallel ...*

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks for the answer, it was really helpful. I'll also take a look at the amphp framework, as you said it could work for me.

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/async looks really interesting, but note that each parallel task would need to have Laravel manually booted: https://github.com/spatie/async/issues/97

Comment: @Ryan as frameworks like Laravel and most others are not intended to run on several tasks / processes / workers, this is in general correct. Nevertheless for the benefit of those parallel tasks a single problem should be calculated so that it runs with many parameters, at best without a framework-environment.
Beside that as info: `github.com/spatie/async` requires Linux/Unix to run asynchronous, it's running in Windows too but only synchronous (always one task only).

Comment: @Joe Watkins Concerning `parallel`: it's a framework for CLI and if it's installed also for the webserver, then the webserver is not usable anymore. So it's advisable to install it in a separate php.ini for cli only. A corresponding hint would be useful in your extensions.

Comment: `amphp` is running quite fast in Windows too and is using all CPU-cores. Nevertheless some issues might occur and break the Loops for some reasons. Surely it might depend on the individual code and use-case, but in my case it never turned out to be very reliable. It's quite possible that I could improve my code, the framework offers many options how to solve a problem.