# How do I make sure data retrieved from Cloud Firestore is up-to-date in PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use Cloud Firestore on a Wordpress website with PHP. I'm working on a page where users can view and remove data from their account. I have buttons on the website for removing data that are connected to an HTML form. When I click on the buttons, the page redirects to `#` and now reflects the new delete. However, when I go back to the original page (without the `#`), it shows the old data on the page, even though the data is updated in Firebase Console. This happens even if I open the original page in a new tab.

Here is the HTML form code:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="dataid" value="1" style="display:none">
<input type="submit" value="Remove from list">
</form>
```

I know the code for removing data works because I can see the data being updated in the Firebase Console. Even after the data is updated, when I open the data management page and run this:

```
print_r($db -> collection("users") -> document(wp_get_current_user() -> user_email) -> snapshot() -> data());
```

it prints the old data. Is there a way to prevent my website from getting old data or does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: You could try to finish the request and close it after doing the request so it does not appear.

Comment: @StefanNeacsu Which request are you talking about? The request to Cloud Firestore? How do I finish or close the request in PHP?

Comment: You can try using multithreading (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications) and see if this would help with the issue on your PHP code