# How can one HTML form input be sent to and get results from two different API's?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, api

I am trying to make a page that gives a 3 day weather forecast with a map.
I am using the Openweathermap API and some PHP to get the forecast.
I am using Google's Maps JavaScript API to get my map.
The page has a single input field. I can make it so that submitting input
will give me the weather forecast. I can make it so that input will give
me the map. But I cannot get both to happen at the same time.

Here is the HTML form

```
<form class="example" method="GET" action="index.php" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
<h3>Type In a Zipcode</h3>
<br><p>For Example 160-0005</p>

<!--test-->
<input id="address" type="textbox" value="" name="q" required>
<button id= "OK!"  type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Here is the PHP

```
 date_default_timezone_set($get['timezone']);
 $city = $_GET['q'];
 $string =  "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=".$city.",jp&units=metric&cnt=3&appid=[API Key]";
```

here is the JavaScript

```
<script>
      "use strict";

      function initMap() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: {
            lat: -34.397,
            lng: 150.644
          }
        });
        const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        document.getElementById("OK!").addEventListener("click", () => {
          geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        });
      }

      function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        const address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode(
          {
            address: address
          },
          (results, status) => {
            if (status === "OK") {
              resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
              });
            } else {
              alert(
                "Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status
              );
            }
          }
        );
      }
    </script>
```

In the HTML form code, if I change the button type to "button", the JavaScript works and displays the map. If I change it to type "submit", the PHP works and gives me the forecast. Not really sure what is going on there. What can I do to enter location information and get the map and the forecast at the same time?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Answer (score 0):

in you javascript:

```
   var address = "<?php isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : ''?>";
   
   function initMap() {
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
      }
    });
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    address !== '' && geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, address);
  }

  // have geocodeAddress accept third param of address
  function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, address) {
       ... rest of your code
```

this is all untested. let me know if its works for your (or doesn't)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I like this idea. I was adding your code and testing. Everything was working fine. But when I added a third parameter (address) to geocodeAddress() it broke. The map would no longer appear on the page.

Comment: broke like how? can check the console maybe to see if there are any related errors

Comment: The console gave me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'address' has already been declared" and it pointed to the following line: const address = document.getElementById("address").value;

Comment: you need to remove `const address = document.getElementById("address").value;` because you're getting address in the param

Comment: That got rid of the error. The map is back but it's location does not update when I put in an address. Weather updates fine. Anyway, I really appreciate your help. I'll keep working on it. If you see the whole file it might give you a better idea. Let me know if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Your form isn't submitted when using the `button` element because you're not specifying the form attribute : [HTML  form Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp)

Also, you will likely have to use a javascript http client to send the form instead of just submitting it. The most known and documented one would be Ajax from jquery.
[jQuery - AJAX get() and post() Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)
This will allow you to send data to your back-end(php) transparently without refreshing the page on each form (post or get request) you make.

Good luck with your project :)

EDIT : CODE edited with form attribute.

```
<form id="form1" class="example" method="GET" action="index.php" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px" >
<h3>Type In a Zipcode</h3>
<br><p>For Example 160-0005</p>

<!--test-->
<input id="address" type="textbox" value="" name="q" required>

<!--When using a button, potentially out of the form block-->
<!--You should fill the "form" attribute based on the form's ID-->
<button id= "OK!"  type="submit" form=form1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></form>
```

Also I don't know if it's only from your sample code but there is a missing `</form>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. I will look into using AJAX. I am sorry, but I could not quite follow your first comment. Would you mind showing me in the code? Do you mean I left out out </form> at the end?

Comment: I edited my answer to demonstrate what I meant. As for jQuery  and Ajax, it should be pretty straight forward to implement.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I added the form attribute in the inside the button so that it matched id of the form. It did not seem to change any of the functionality when running the program though. Should I have noticed a change?