# Why am I getting file not found when using this popen command?

Tags: php

I'm attempting to use this code from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350418/3672303

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    // open ten processes
    for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
        $pipe[$j] = popen('script2.php', 'w');
    }

    // wait for them to finish
    for ($j=0; $j<10; ++$j) {
        pclose($pipe[$j]);
    }
}
```

When I execute it, I get the following:

```
sh: 1: script2.php: not found
sh: 1: script2.php: not found
sh: 1: script2.php: not found...... (repeated a bunch of times)
```

script2.php is in the same directory.  I tried using the full path to the file, and my result is the same.

I'm assuming it could be some type of weird PHP path/environment issue?...  How do I fix?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try `popen(__DIR__ . '/script2.php', 'w')`

Comment: popen executes from the context of php's current directory.   Give it a path to the script you want to execute.

Comment: @Sysix I tried popen(__DIR__ . '/script2.php', 'w') and the error message changed to:  /fullpath/script2.php: 1: /fullpath/script2.php: cannot open ?PHP: No such file
/fullpath/script2.php: 3: /fullpath/script2.php: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: The contents of script2.php has no errors when ran alone.  It just echos out a test message.  echo "test";

Comment: My first guess is that your computer doesn't know how to run PHP files by themselves, they aren't executable. I think you need to run `popen('php ' . __DIR__ . '/script2.php', 'w')`, and the `php` might need to be fully qualified, too, such as `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: @ChrisHaas This worked!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Chris Hass" in the comments above came up with the solution.  Changing this line worked.

```
$pipe[$j] = popen('script2.php', 'w');   // Does not work
```

to

```
popen('php ' . __DIR__ . '/script2.php', 'w')  // Works correctly.
```