# High traffic php script offloading aws sns messages to another script/server

Tags: php, performance, architecture, amazon-sns

I have a php script which processes around 1000 or more requests every minute. I want to send for every request an SNS message to AWS. But i do not want the performance to be affected. So i was thinking to create a new file for every request and make another script process those one by one and send messages to AWS SNS.

I'm not sure if i should create a new file for each request or append to an existing file. If i append i have the risk of blocking the second script when it wants to read of the file.

Using a database is not an option because it adds too much latency.

What do you guys suggest i do?

Comment: Disk I/O can have latency/overhead just like a database. Have you tried just pushing the SNS messages directly from the PHP script? It might not be as bad as you imagine. Have you quantified the overhead which sending each individual message adds?

Comment: `So i was thinking to create a new file for every request and make another script process those one by one and send messages to AWS SNS`...this sounds like basically it would end up needing another publish/subscribe type of job queue to notify the second script - which, ironically, is exactly what SNS is for.

Comment: Just directly use the SNS client to publish the message - why do you want to use files or a database? Have you encountered issues using the SDK directly?

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with at least *attempting* to use the SNS client and benchmarking your performance, writing to SNS may not be significantly more overhead than writing to a file (especially once you work through all the transactional locking processes needed to deal with files effectively, you WILL run into race conditions).

If the latency overhead for the SNS is too high and is blocking your throughput, you might want to look at multi-threading, offloading the SNS processing to a separate thread: [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications).  If you need to go out-of-process, you should look long and hard at a queue, either something stand-alone, or even plain old IPC queues: https://nomadphp.com/blog/52/php-ipc-with-daemon-service-using-message-queues-shared-memory-and-semaphores

If you decide you *have* to use files, think long and hard about whether a database (even an in-memory database) might be more effective.  Managing locking is a non-trivial process, and having two processes read/write to the same file or file-system requires understanding deep things about your filesystem like buffers and atomicity that you may not be prepared for.  A database is *designed* for these sorts of operations (as are queues).